# how to show alphabet data if i select model and category

Tags: php, mysql

this code is showing numeric data only and i have a problem in this code and i have all alphabet data in both rows model and category so how can i fix it to show alphabet data please help me to fix this issue thanks

```
    //////Displaying Data/////////////
$model=$_GET['model']; // Collecting data from query string
if(!is_numeric($model)){ // Checking data it is a number or not
echo "Data Error model"; 
exit;
}
$category=$_GET['category']; // Collecting data from query string
if(!is_numeric($category)){ // Checking data it is a number or not
echo "Data Error category"; 
exit;
}
```

complete code

```
    //connect to database

     mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
     mysql_select_db('dataweb');

//////Displaying Data/////////////
$model=$_GET['model']; // Collecting data from query string
if(!is_numeric($model)){ // Checking data it is a number or not
echo "Data Error model"; 
exit;
}
$category=$_GET['category']; // Collecting data from query string
if(!is_numeric($category)){ // Checking data it is a number or not
echo "Data Error category"; 
exit;
}
$result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); //the main trick
$q=mysql_query("select * from data where model=$model And category=$category AND TRIM(model) IS NOT NULL");

//Adds one to the counter
 mysql_query("UPDATE data SET counter = counter + 1 where model=$model ");

 //Retreives the current count
 $count = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT counter FROM data"));
$row=mysql_fetch_object($q);

echo mysql_error();
?><table class='hovertable'><?php if($row->model):?><tr class=\"style1\"><td width='200'><b>Model:</b></td><td><?php echo $row->model ?></td></tr><?php endif; ?>
<?php if($row->category):?><tr class=\"style1\"><td width='200'><b>Category:</b></td><td><?php echo $row->category?></td></tr><?php endif; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: From the PHP docs - `mysql_fetch_row` — Get a result row as an enumerated array.... if you want column names, you should use [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: You should also stop using the MySQL interface and switch to using the MySQLi interface, with prepared statements and bind variables to prevent SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the assumption that what you asked for is to check if `$model` and `$category` are strings or not. Also, i have used mysqli_* functions because mysql_* are deprecated but you should use PDO instead.

```
<?php
//Connect to database
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'dataweb');// Establishing Connection with Server
mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
}

//////Displaying Data/////////////
$model = trim($_GET['model']); // Collecting data from query string
if (!is_string($model)) { // Checking data it is a string or not
    echo "Data Error model"; 
    exit;
}
$category = trim($_GET['category']); // Collecting data from query string
if (!is_string($category)) { // Checking data it is a string or not
    echo "Data Error category"; 
    exit;
}

$model = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $model);
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $category);

//Select your data
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE model = '$model' And category = '$category' AND TRIM(model) IS NOT NULL;";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);

//Adds one to the counter
$query2 = "UPDATE data SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE model = '$model';";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);

//Retreives the current count for all data
$query3 = "SELECT counter FROM data;";
$result3 = mysqli_query($connection, $query3);
?>

<table class="hovertable">

    <?php if (!empty($row1['model'])): ?>
    <tr class="style1">
        <td width="200"><b>Model:</b></td>
        <td><?php echo $row1['model']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (!empty($row1['category'])):?>
    <tr class="style1">
        <td width="200"><b>Category:</b></td>
        <td><?php echo $row1['category']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>

</table>
```